# Chosen JS Search by keyword

Tags: javascript, jquery-chosen

Is there anyway to make chosen look at more than just an options text for the search functionality?

for instance:

```
<select>
    <option data-keywords="circle,ball,sphere">Circle</option>
    <option data-keywords="rectangle,square">Rectangle</option>
</select>
```

It wouldn't have to do the match underlining on keywords, it would only do the result match underlining if it matched text like it does by default.

If its not native how would I add this in javascript if it has not already been done before.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A fairly down-to-earth, quick solution can be applied as follows.

**Please note**

This solution requires/assumes:

- Chosen Version 1.1.0
- A `data-keywords` attribute for each `option` tag
- Keywords separated by a comma within the `data-keywords` attribute

Ok, so let's get to it.

Open your jquery.chosen.js file.

(You will not be able to use the minified version).

---

**1. Assure storage of data attribute in local options**

> **Location** => add_option()

**Full Definition**

> SelectParser.prototype.add_option = function(option, group_position, group_disabled) {}

**Edit**

Look for `this.parsed.push()` and at the bottom of the definition, just below `style`, add this code:

```
keywords: ($(option).data().keywords!==undefined 
   ? $(option).data().keywords.split(',') 
   : false)
```

---

**2. Make sure the keywords are parsed by the search function**

> **Location** => winnow_results()

**Full Definition**

```
AbstractChosen.prototype.winnow_results = function() {}
```

**Edit**

**2.1** Add a new variable `keywordMatch` to top declaration:

> var escapedSearchText, option, regex, regexAnchor, results, results_group, searchText, startpos, text, zregex, _i, _len, _ref;

Becomes:

> var escapedSearchText, option, regex, regexAnchor, results, results_group, searchText, startpos, text, zregex, _i, _len, _ref, **keywordMatch**;

**2.2** Find this condition: `if (!(option.group && !this.group_search)){}` and after the second line (where `option.search_match` is set), add this code:

```
keywordMatch=(option.keywords && option.keywords.indexOf(searchText) > -1);
if(keywordMatch)
    option.search_match=true;
```

**2.3** Find this assignment:

```
option.search_text = text.substr(0, startpos) + '<em>' + text.substr(startpos);
```

And replace it with this code:

```
option.search_text = keywordMatch ? text : (text.substr(0, startpos) + '<em>' + text.substr(startpos));
```

---

These modifications come in the form of a quick implementation. If you need more options (for instance that the keywords are not case-sensitive), you need to implement these parts yourself.

Let me know if there are problems or if i forgot anything.

Comment: This is really well thought out. Any reason they don't support it already?

Comment: Hmm, if i type k it doesnt match when the keyword is kjoc... it only works on full match

Comment: That's correct. However, you can easily implement the desired behaviour. Check **2.2**, where we use `indexOf()`. In the given example we compare the string by looking for full occurrences within `option.keywords`. If you want to allow for a more flexible filtering mechanism, you can map a comparison function on each entry of `option.keywords`. As for the lack of support - i guess it was never a requirement by their project.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks SquareCat for your great solution! I wanted to have the ability to search using multiple keywords (including partial keywords) so I developed some crude code that does the job.

**Adding onto SquareCats solution:**

Instead of using:

```
keywordMatch=(option.keywords && option.keywords.indexOf(searchText) > -1);
```

Use this instead:

```
keywordMatch=this.keyword_string_match(option.keywords,searchText);
```

And add this function:

```
AbstractChosen.prototype.keyword_string_match = function(keyword_array, searchtextstring) {
  var value, searchlength, searchterm;
  var continuetonext = "";
  var searchstring = searchtextstring; 
  var wordmatchcounter = 0;
  if (searchstring !== ""){
    searchstring = searchstring.split(' ');
      for (searchterm = 0 ; searchterm < searchstring.length; searchterm++ ){
        if (continuetonext == "" || continuetonext == true){
          continuetonext = false;
          searchtext = searchstring[searchterm];
          for (var i = 0; i < keyword_array.length; ++i) {
              value = keyword_array[i];
              searchlength = searchtext.length;
              if (value.substring(0, searchlength) === searchtext) {
               continuetonext = true;
               wordmatchcounter++;     
              }else{
                continuetonext = false;
              };
          };
       };
      };
    if (wordmatchcounter == searchterm){return true}else{return false};
  }else{return false};
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe something like that will work:

**JavaScript**

```
document.getElementById('filter-input').onkeyup = function () {
  filter(this.value, document.getElementById('select-input'));
};

function filter(value, input) {
  var children = input.children,
      found = false,
      keywords;
  children = Array.prototype.slice.call(children);
  children.forEach(function (c) {
    c.removeAttribute('selected');
  });
  children.forEach(function (c) {
    keywords = c.getAttribute('data-keywords').split(',');
    keywords.forEach(function (k) {
      if (k === value) {
        found = true;
        c.setAttribute('selected', true);
        return;
      }
    });
    if (found) return;
  });
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/xecepupu/1/edit)